# NoSuchMethodException when using reflection to instantiate protected constructor

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, protected

This is the first time I am using the reflection and do not know what mistake I am doing in instantiating the protected constructor. Below is my code to instantiate a constructor of [JsonProcessingException](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html).

getDeclaredConstructor is causing NoSuchMethodException, though this exception class has protected constructor with one, two and three parameters.

```
final Constructor<JsonProcessingException> constructor = 
    JsonProcessingException.class
        .getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class, Object.class);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
```

My Assumption: I have read that we can instantiate a private constructor using reflection so I am assuming the protected can also be instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to consider the types of the arguments of the constructor not only the numbers. The [JsonProcessingException](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html) does not have a constructor that takes two `Object`s as arguments but one that takes a `String` and a `JsonLocation` as well as one taking a `String` and a `Throwable`. To access the second constructor write it like this:

```
final Constructor<JsonProcessingException> constructor = 
    JsonProcessingException.class
        .getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{String.class, Throwable.class});
constructor.setAccessible(true);
JsonProcessingException ex = constructor.newInstance(msg, throwable);
```

See also http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is almost correct but you are trying to reflect nonexistent constructor. You have to pass correct signature for example

```
JsonProcessingException.class
    .getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Throwable.class)
```

Comment: is not passing Object.class a generic way of getting any constructor with single argument?

Comment: @Vishwanathgowdak no (unless argument type is really and `Object`). you have to know argument types. if you  need less strict match then you should traverse `getDeclaredConstructors()` to find which constructor is suitable